# Docker swarm giving out weird error from log

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

When I join another host machine as a worker to my swarm the log gives me this error

```
ERRO[2021-05-06T16:27:16.208574765+07:00] Could not open netlink handle during vni population for ns /var/run/docker/netns/1-p0wju48aad: failed to set into network namespace 21 while creating netlink socket: invalid argument
```

How to solve this guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this error could just a random error in my VM for no reason so this could be ignored